# Getting URL Variables with a Rewritten Page (Login Page)

Tags: url-rewriting, get-posts

As part of a larger project, I am attempting all login activity to occur at the following address:

www.url.com/login

So, a link that should lead to a form that would allow a user to reset their password would be found at the following:

www.url.com/login?action=lostpassword

However, the wp-login.php is not reading this correctly, and when I go to the above address, I get the normal log-in form.

This is how I have it set up:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_virtual_page_template' );
function add_virtual_page_template()
{
    global $wp, $wp_rewrite;

    $wp->add_query_var( 'template' );

    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'login', EP_PERMALINK | EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'login/?', 'index.php?template=login', 'top' );

    add_rewrite_rule( 'login/?', 'index.php?template=login', 'top' );

    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'add_virtual_page_redirect' );
function add_virtual_page_redirect()
{
    global $wp;

    $queryvar = get_query_var('template');

    if ($queryvar && $queryvar == 'login')
    {
        include(site_url('wp-login.php'));
        exit();
    }

    if ($queryvar == 'mylogin')
    {
        include( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/page-login.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want instead of redirect to `wp-login` the user redirect to `login` page then use the following code. It will redirect user to `login` page where login form is present.

```
add_filter('site_url',  'wplogin_filter', 10, 3);
function wplogin_filter( $url, $path, $orig_scheme ){
    $old = array( "/(wp-login\.php)/");
    $new = array( "login/");
    return preg_replace( $old, $new, $url, 1);
}

add_action('init','possibly_redirect');
function possibly_redirect(){
    global $pagenow;
    if( 'wp-login.php' == $pagenow ){
        wp_redirect(site_url( $path = 'login'));
    exit();
    }
}
```

In login form ckeck the value of action. For login use [`wp_signon()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function.

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['action'])) { ?>
      <div>Login with the Email
        <form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>" method="post">
          <table style="float: left;">
            <tr>
              <td><label>User Name</label></td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" placeholder="Enter your username">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><label>Password</label></td>
              <td>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter password"><br>
                <a href="<?php echo site_url('login/?action=lostpassword') ?> "> Forgot Your Password ? </a><br>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="login-submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
<?php
}
```

For lost password. Create form in the same `login page`

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && 'lostpassword'== $_REQUEST['action'])
{
  ?>

  <div id="tab3_login" class="tab_content_login" >
   <p>Enter your username or email to reset your password.</p>
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('login/?action=tg_pwd_reset') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
    <div class="username">
      <label>Username or Email : </label>
      <input type="text" name="user_login" value="" size="20" id="user_login" />
      <?php toolTip('user_login', 'Username');?>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Reset my password'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="1002" />
  </form>
</div>
<?php
}
```